# adding advertising clips for HTML5 videoPlayer

Tags: html, html5-video, video-player

I'm using HTML 5 video player and I need to add advertising clips at the begging of my videos . Is it possible to do that?If so ,How should I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO,please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very large question, many solutions!

It's very hard to implement it yourself but, for exemple, VideoJS (free HTML5 video player) with the plugin "contrib-ads" fill your needs.

- VideoJS: http://videojs.com/
- VideoJS ads-contrib: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads

Hope this help you.

Comment: ,i'm trying to display a video  using videojs-contrib-ads and video.js . I have searched a lot and I couldn't find an example.Could you give me an example of that?

Comment: http://videojs.com/getting-started/ followed by http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/plugins.html. If you follow all these steps, you will be able to use VideoJS and ad plugin :)